# How can one verify if the FCC/CE certification mark on an electronic component or product is genuine?

Tags: fcc, certification, ce

Some companies can be unscrupulous and simply paste a label to fake FCC CE. How can one be sure the label is real?

Is there a website for checking the validity of the FCC CE mark?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Search the FCC database by their stated FCC ID code:
http://transition.fcc.gov/oet/ea/fccid/ The first 3 or 5 characters is the Grantee Code (assigned to a company).

There isn't an equivalent for CE.

Comment: I've created a FCC ID Database at https://fccid.io which is a little bit easier to search. If it's a wireless device, you should be able to look up the FCC ID on that site and get the test reports certifying the device.

Comment: Note - the FCC ID is only required for intentional transmitters.

Answer (score 4):

CE can be self-certified, so there's no central register of products.

The manufacturer is still obliged to keep records of the certification process: they should be able to give you a copy of their report.

Comment: If it can be self-certified, wouldn't it lead to lots of cheating? Product makers would just pass themselves so that they can start selling their products.

Comment: @user768421 some tests need to be done in accredited labs... So electronic products might need some official testing. But I'm sure there's a lot of cheating too.

Comment: CE: Caveat Emptor :)

Comment: Self certification requires that the manufacturer has reasonable grounds for believing that they comply. Generally this means a test report from a certified lab however for something that is a minor change they may simply self declare that it is sufficiently similar to the prior product that the old tests are still valid. All manufacturers should be able to provide a declaration of conformity upon request indicating why they believe they are in spec.